# Create dropdown menu for login account

Tags: html, css, django, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I would like to create a dropdown menu from the logged-in user account. currently, the top-right button in the navigation bar is either "Login" or "Logout" based on if user is logged in. I would hope to create a dropdown menu when user is logged in, which contains options such as account and logout. The desired examples look like below:

[image]

The login dropdown menu can contain two options (Account and Logout). how to achieve this, without using boostrap external stylesheet?

**Current HTML**

```
   <div class="nav">
      <div class="login-container">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="get">
            <span>Welcome, {{ user }}.&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <button type="submit">logout</button>
            {% else %}
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="get">
            <span>Welcome, {{ user }}.&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <button type="submit">login</button>
          {% endif %}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What did you try? You can use pure CSS(https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/ALbdbJ) or JS (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) hopefully you don't expect a complete solution..

Comment: Bootstrap templates offer you this possibility. You should check it out.

Comment: I cannot use bootstrp because it will mess up many styles of my current page

Comment: some code demonstration is more useful

Comment: @vfioox those are not my solution as drop down menue cannot extend outside the navigation bar, a large portion of it will will be covered by (beneth) the body part